# Fencing with only area of $3$ square feet

Tags: differential-geometry

> If I had $6$ feet of fencing could I fence a region that has area $3$
>   square feet?

So, I must show that there is a curve in the plane of my fencing that has length $6$ feet that bounds the region of area.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the isoperimetric inequality states that the length of a closed curve $L$  and the enclosed area $A$ satisfy $4\pi A\le L^{2}$.

So if you could find such a curve in the plane then by the isoperimetric inequality $12\pi=4\pi(3)\le6^{2}=36$.

But $\pi>3$ so $12\pi>36$. Contradiction. Hence no such curve exists.

Comment: Thank you, I just been taught isoperimetric inequality.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: For a given perimeter, a disk has the largest area. Does a disk with a circumference of $6$ have area $\ge 3$, or not?

Comment: Thanks and no it does not. It has $\le 3$. Will just mentioning that complete the prove?

Comment: @Lays: Less than $3$, actually, and you need the strict inequality. Assuming that you’re allowed to use the fact that I mentioned in my first sentence, that does indeed show that the answer to the question is *no*: if you could fence such a region, you could fence a disk with an area of $\ge 3$ ft, but as you say, you can’t.

Comment: @Lays: You’re welcome!